# Using custom CSS3/HTML on generated pages?

Tags: views, panels, theming

I created new pages on my (soon to be) photography website using Panels and Views. I want to have my own hover effects for pictures on my albums page. How am I supposed to use custom HTML and CSS3 animations like those found [here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/OriginalHoverEffects/index8.html) on these images which are loaded by modules such as Panels and Drupal which are basically creating their own markup on the page load i.e. not in hard coded files which I can add markup to.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. This question is off-topic as per [FAQ].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the views template and create your own template/markup to achieve what you want.  You can read more on how to achieve that here: http://drupal.org/node/1089656